# Shared library in Jenkins with pipeline script

Tags: devops

In vars I have tagdeploy.groovy in which parameters are docker repo and image name...how I call that groovy file in my pipeline script and deploy...any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Jenkins shared library, under your shared library vars folder you have this file called ‘tagdeploy.groovy’ which has a function call() - then you can call this inside scripted or declarative Pipeline using its direct name like a function call - tagdeploy()